# ::webkit-scrollbar не видит css переменные

Tags: css, scss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тот самый фрагмент кода, в файрфоксе все почему то defined и скроллбар действительно кастомизировался

```
// .fs-manager scroll
.fs-manager {

  scrollbar-color: var(--color-1) var(--color-2);


  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: var(--color-1);
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: var(--color-2);
  }
}
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Со свойством `scrollbar-color` в принципе картина удручающая https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollbar-color

Comment: @Quazimorda так именно оно и работает как надо, проблема с ::webkit-scrollbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы заработали вебкиты, нужно явно задать основные размеры полос прокрутки. Я добавил так:

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

И всё нормально заработало. Ясно, что свойства указать можно у вашего класса, а не вообще, ну и размеры и цвета можно задать такие, какие именно вам нужны.